Syntax error or access violation: 1064 SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
I have a Laravel 5.4 application. I have a code that generates and runs a query as below:
/**
     * Returns stats data
     *
     * @param $start_date
     * @param $end_date
     * @param $trackingCategoryId
     * @param string $sort_field
     * @param string $sort_direction
     * @param null $page
     * @param null $per_page
     * @return array
     */
    public function getStatsForPeriod($start_date, $end_date, $trackingCategoryId, $sort_field = 'total_opened', $sort_direction = 'ASC', $page = null, $per_page = null) {
        $rows = [];

        if (!empty($start_date) && !empty($end_date)) {
            $q = DB::table($this->table)
                        ->select(DB::raw('SQL_CACHE
                                          SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
                                          stat_users_events_daily.user_id,
                                          stat_users_events_daily.tracking_category_id as tracking_category_id,
                                          IF(ISNULL(tracking_categories.name),"Category not found",tracking_categories.name) as tracking_category_name,
                                          SUM(stat_users_events_daily.sent) AS total_sent,
                                          SUM(stat_users_events_daily.opened) AS total_opened')
                        )
                        ->leftJoin('tracking_categories', 'stat_users_events_daily.tracking_category_id', '=', 'tracking_categories.id')
                        ->whereBetween('stat_date', [$start_date, $end_date])
                        ->groupBy('user_id','tracking_category_id')
                        ->orderBy($sort_field, $sort_direction)

                        //Default sort by grouped fields
                        ->orderBy('user_id','ASC')
                        ->orderBy('tracking_category_id','ASC');

            if (!empty($page) && !empty($per_page)) {
                $q->skip(($page-1) * $per_page)
                  ->take($per_page);
            }

            if (!empty($trackingCategoryId)) {
            $q->where('tracking_category_id', $trackingCategoryId);
            }

            $rows = $q->get();

            $found_rows = DB::select('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total');

            //Complement stats with additional data
            foreach($rows as &$row) {
                $row->last_sending_date = StatEvent::getLastActionTimestamp($row->user_id, $row->tracking_category_id, EventAction::SEND);
                $row->last_opening_date = StatEvent::getLastActionTimestamp($row->user_id, $row->tracking_category_id, EventAction::OPEN);
            }
        }

        return ['rows' => $rows, 'total' => (is_array($found_rows) && (!empty($found_rows[0]))) ? $found_rows[0]->total : 0];
    }

This code runs fine in MySQL 5.7
I moved to MySQL 8.4.0 and I started to get the below error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
stat_users_events_' at line 2 (SQL: select SQL_CACHE
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
stat_users_events_daily.user_id,
stat_users_events_daily.tracking_category_id as tracking_category_id,
IF(ISNULL(tracking_categories.name),"Category not found",tracking_categories.name) as tracking_category_name,
SUM(stat_users_events_daily.sent) AS total_sent,
SUM(stat_users_events_daily.opened) AS total_opened from `stat_users_events_daily` left join `tracking_categories` on `stat_users_events_daily`.`tracking_category_id` = `tracking_categories`.`id` where `stat_date` between 2024-08-24 and 2024-08-24 group by `user_id`, `tracking_category_id` order by `total_opened` desc, `user_id` asc, `tracking_category_id` asc limit 2 offset 0)

I tried to find a solution online as it seems SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and FOUND_ROWS() are no longer available in MySQL 8 but I could not find any reliable solution. I replaced SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with COUNT(*) with no luck. Any hep please?
